# Why do chromosome pairs have different shapes and sizes?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, chromosome

When I look at microscopic images of human chromosome pairs I see that they have different shapes and sizes.

Is there a deeper biological reason for that? Is there some evolutionary pressure for them to be this way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Chromosomes *are* different sizes - they have different numbers of base pairs in them. That's why they look different...

Comment: @MattDMo They are curved at different angles. Why are the angles different? Why are they not all straight lines?

Comment: Because the nucleus is crowded, and there isn't enough room for all of them - especially the longer ones - to be stretched out straight. If you haven't already, please read the [Wikipedia article on karyotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karyotype).

Comment: Think of the chromosomes as a bunch of ropes of different lengths (i.e. size in base pairs). if you quickly try to sort out a bunch of ropes on the ground with a long pole from a platform 50 feet up (basically how karyotype images are created), do you expect the ropes to be straight, or for some of them to have some wiggle?